# Configurable Swatches on Listing Page: Show Multiple Color Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, color-swatches, swatches

Currently Magento 1.9.1.0 allows to show only a single attribute on the listing page as a swatch (product details page can have multiple attributes showing).

Since I've 30+ manufacturers (and each has about 20+ colors), I've a separate color attribute for each manufacturer. I would like that all of my different color attributes will show on the listing page.

How can I make it happen?

Thank you in advanced for any tip.

Answer (score 1):

In the module the `app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productlist.php` is the helper which determines which `_swatchAttributeId` should be used.

You could extend this module and rewrite the helper.
Rewrite the `getSwatchAttributeId` function and do you own magic.

You could

- just add some id logic, `Mage::registry('current_category')->getCategoryId()`
- add a custom option for a category which you can set per category
- read it from the attributeset used for the first product

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a direct answer I feel it still has merit. Having multiple attributes for colors by different manufacturers could lead to a namespace conflict.

For example if you have attributes `nike_color` and `reebok_color` and both have an option "Red", you might get the wrong swatch if you upload `red.png` to `/media/wysiwyg/swatches/red.png`.

For this reason I feel the need to prefix the swatch name with some kind of namespace indicator.