# How to show multiple attribute swatches on product listing page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog

Magento allows showing only a single swatch attribute on the product listing page.
Is there a way to show more than 1 swatch attribute on the  product listing page?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Create a module :{your_module_name}

Step 2:
/app/code/local/D1m/{your_module_name}/etc/system.xml

```
<config>
<sections>
    <configswatches translate="label" module="configurableswatches">
        <groups>
            <general translate="label" module="configurableswatches">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <product_list_attribute translate="label">
                        <label>Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>configurableswatches/system_config_source_catalog_product_configattribute_select</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </product_list_attribute>
                </fields>
            </general>
        </groups>
    </configswatches>
</sections>
```

Step 3: /app/code/local/D1m/{your_module_name}/etc/config.xml **update your xml...**

```
<helpers><configurableswatches></configurableswatches></helpers><models><configurableswatches><rewrite><observer>D1m_{your_module_name}_Model_ConfigurableSwatches_Observer</observer>
```

Step 4:/app/code/local/D1m/{your_module_name}/Helper/ConfigurableSwatches/Productlist.php
class D1m_{your_module_name}_Helper_ConfigurableSwatches_Productlist extends Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productlist {
    protected $_swatchAttributeIds;

```
protected $_swatchAttributes;

/**
 * Get ID of the attribute that should be used for swatches on product listing
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSwatchAttributeIds()
{
    if (is_null($this->_swatchAttributeIds)) {
        $this->_swatchAttributeIds =
            Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::CONFIG_PATH_LIST_SWATCH_ATTRIBUTE);
    }
    return $this->_swatchAttributeIds;
}

/**
 * Get model of attribute that should be used for swatches on product listing
 */
public function getSwatchAttributes()
{
    $attributeIds = explode(',',$this->getSwatchAttributeIds());
    $attributeCode = array();
    foreach ( $attributeIds as $attributeId ) {
        $attributeCode[] = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
            ->load($attributeId)->getAttributeCode();
    }
    return $attributeCode;
}
```

}

Step 5:/app/code/local/D1m/{your_module_name}/Helper/ConfigurableSwatches/Mediafallback.php
class D1m_{your_module_name}_Helper_ConfigurableSwatches_Mediafallback extends Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback {

```
/**
 * Set child_attribute_label_mapping on products with attribute label -> product mapping
 * Depends on following product data:
 * - product must have children products attached
 *
 * @param array $parentProducts
 * @param $storeId
 * @return void
 */
public function attachConfigurableProductChildrenAttributeMapping(array $parentProducts, $storeId)
{
    $listSwatchAttr = Mage::helper('d1m_productoptionsimage/configurableSwatches_productlist')
        ->getSwatchAttributeIds();
    $listSwatchAttr = explode(',',$listSwatchAttr);

    $parentProductIds = array();
    /* @var $parentProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    foreach ($parentProducts as $parentProduct) {
        $parentProductIds[] = $parentProduct->getId();
    }

    $configAttributes = Mage::getResourceModel('configurableswatches/catalog_product_attribute_super_collection')
                            ->addParentProductsFilter($parentProductIds)
                            ->attachEavAttributes()
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ;

    $optionLabels = array();
    foreach ($configAttributes as $attribute) {
        $optionLabels += $attribute->getOptionLabels();
    }

    foreach ($parentProducts as $parentProduct) {
        $mapping = array();
        $listSwatchValues = array();

        /* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute */
        foreach ($configAttributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $childProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            if (!is_array($parentProduct->getChildrenProducts())) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($parentProduct->getChildrenProducts() as $childProduct) {
                // product has no value for attribute, we can't process it
                if (!$childProduct->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    continue;
                }
                $optionId = $childProduct->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());

                // if we don't have a default label, skip it
                if (!isset($optionLabels[$optionId][0])) {
                    continue;
                }

                // normalize to all lower case before we start using them
                $optionLabels = array_map(function ($value) {
                    return array_map('Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::normalizeKey', $value);
                }, $optionLabels);

                // using default value as key unless store-specific label is present
                $optionLabel = $optionLabels[$optionId][0];
                if (isset($optionLabels[$optionId][$storeId])) {
                    $optionLabel = $optionLabels[$optionId][$storeId];
                }

                // initialize arrays if not present
                if (!isset($mapping[$optionLabel])) {
                    $mapping[$optionLabel] = array(
                        'product_ids' => array(),
                    );
                }
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['product_ids'][] = $childProduct->getId();
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['label'] = $optionLabel;
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['default_label'] = $optionLabels[$optionId][0];
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['labels'] = $optionLabels[$optionId];
                if (in_array($attribute->getAttributeId(),$listSwatchAttr)
                    && !in_array($mapping[$optionLabel]['label'], $listSwatchValues)
                ) {
                    $listSwatchValues[$optionId] = $mapping[$optionLabel]['label'];
                }
            } // end looping child products
        } // end looping attributes


        foreach ($mapping as $key => $value) {
            $mapping[$key]['product_ids'] = array_unique($mapping[$key]['product_ids']);
        }

        $parentProduct->setChildAttributeLabelMapping($mapping)
                      ->setListSwatchAttrValues($listSwatchValues);
    } // end looping parent products
}

/**
 * Determines which product attributes should be selected
 * when children products are attached to parent products
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getChildrenProductsAttributes()
{
    $color_size_attribute = Mage::helper('d1m_productoptionsimage/configurableSwatches_productlist')
        ->getSwatchAttributes();
    $default_attribute = array(
        'small_image',
        'image',
        'image_label',
        'small_image_label',
    );
    return array_merge($color_size_attribute,$default_attribute);
}

/**
 * Attaches children product to each product via
 * ->setChildrenProducts()
 *
 * @param array $products
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return void
 */
public function attachChildrenProducts(array $products, $storeId)
{
    $productIds = array();
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productIds[] = $product->getId();
    }

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel(
        'configurableswatches/catalog_product_type_configurable_product_collection');

    $collection->setFlag('product_children', true)
               ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
               ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_getChildrenProductsAttributes());
    $collection->addProductSetFilter($productIds);
    $collection->load();

    $mapping = array();
    /* @var $childProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    foreach ($collection as $childProduct) {
        foreach ($childProduct->getParentIds() as $parentId) {
            if (!isset($mapping[$parentId])) {
                $mapping[$parentId] = array();
            }
            $mapping[$parentId][] = $childProduct;
        }
    }

    foreach ($mapping as $parentId => $childrenProducts) {
        $products[$parentId]->setChildrenProducts($childrenProducts);
    }
}
```

}

Step 6:/app/code/local/D1m/{your_module_name}/Model/ConfigurableSwatches/Observer.php
class D1m_{your_module_name}_Model_ConfigurableSwatches_Observer extends Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Observer {

```
/**
 * Attach children products after product list load
 * Observes: catalog_block_product_list_collection
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function productListCollectionLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!Mage::helper('configurableswatches')->isEnabled()) { // check if functionality disabled
        return; // exit without loading swatch functionality
    }

    /* @var $helper Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback */
    $helper = Mage::helper('{your_module_name}/configurableSwatches_mediafallback');

    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();

    if ($collection
        instanceof Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product_Type_Configurable_Product_Collection) {
        // avoid recursion
        return;
    }

    $products = $collection->getItems();

    $helper->attachChildrenProducts($products, $collection->getStoreId());

    $helper->attachConfigurableProductChildrenAttributeMapping($products, $collection->getStoreId());

    $helper->attachGallerySetToCollection($products, $collection->getStoreId());

    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $helper->groupMediaGalleryImages($product);
        Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')
            ->indexProductImages($product, $product->getListSwatchAttrValues());
    }

}
```

}

### Enjoy!

[Configurable Swatches on Listing Page: Show Multiple Color Attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60799/configurable-swatches-on-listing-page-show-multiple-color-attributes)

Comment: it's not working,  any suggestions about that ?