# I want to display the color and size of the configurable product in the catalog product list page

Tags: configurable-product, catalog, color-swatches

I am using magento 1.9.3,I want to display both color and size of the configurable product in the catalog product list page. now i have the color only. if I change it to size in configuration, then it shows size. I want both on list page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento 1.9.x allows showing only a single swatch attribute on the product listing page. As you can see below, this configuration setting allows to select only one option.
[image]

Check also similar post with offered solution

[How to show multiple attribute swatches on product listing page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109720/how-to-show-multiple-attribute-swatches-on-product-listing-page)